# HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread() becoming null

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool, hystrix, netflix

In my springboot app, I am wrapping a code block with HystrixCommand annotation to indicate that the code block is protected. 
Also I am using THREAD as hystrix execution isolation strategy. Since the code block runs in a separate thread(hystrix-{protected method's commandKey}-x), I'm injecting MDC by writing a custom HystrixCommandExecutionHook to add the unique id in all the logs to make debugging easier. And I've registered the custom plugin when the app starts.

I am initialising HystrixRequestContext in *onStart()* method of HystrixCommandExecutionHook.

In the code block, I also have a call to cache service before calling remote service which runs again on a *separate hystrix thread. I got to know this by checking the thread name(hystrix-{cacheService's commandKey}-x)* from the logs.

```
@Override
 public <T> void onStart(HystrixInvokable<T> commandInstance) {
   HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
   Map<String, String> originalMDCContext = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
   if (originalMDCContext != null && !originalMDCContext.isEmpty()) {
      mdcContextVariable.set(originalMDCContext);
    }
  }
```

The challenge I am facing is , when the call to cache service is complete and control comes back to the next line in the code block, the value of *HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread()* will be *null*. I saw *HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized()* will have *FALSE* value. If code block throws an exception, cleanup in onExecutionFailure method fails with NPE. The cleanup code is like below:

```
private void cleanup() {
  HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread().shutdown();
}
```

Since I am getting null in *HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread()*, *cleanup()* is failing with NPE on executionSuccess/ executionFailure.

Can anybody please shed some lights on what is happening here? Why is the **HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread()** becoming **null** or why the **HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized()** becomes **false** after returning from other service call?

#### Workaround

Currently I am checking in cleanup method if HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized() is TRUE and then invoke the *shutdown()* method. If it's FALSE, don't do anything.

```
private void cleanup() {
if(HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized() == Boolean.TRUE)
  HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread().shutdown();
}
```

#### Expected

I expect HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread() should contain the state(shouldn't be null) until I invoke *shutdown()* on it manually.

#### Actual

HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread() is having null after call returns from other service

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some dummy code for the services with `hystrixCommand` and the place where `cleanup()` method is called, so that NPE can be replicated